# How to combine Json schemas

Tags: c#, json, json.net, schema

I have a C# application that contains multiple classes with properties that correspond to entries in a Json file.
I would like to validate the Json file against a Json schema which I will create using NewtonSoft's schema generator for types e.g.
`JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(ClassName))`.
My problem is that this will generate one Json schema per class and I want to validate the Json file against all of them.
How can I combine the Json schemas into one big super schema?

Comment: It might help if you can provide more information on how these multiple classes interact in this "super schema." Is each class a sub-property? Are they overlapping (e.g. properties from various classes mixed in the same JSON object)? Perhaps include more of your code, in a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) format? In addition to making things more clear, that also makes it easier for someone helping you, because they don't have rewrite all your classes etc from scratch

Answer (score 0):

After generation of schemas, If you want the schemas to make one then you can use this `oneOf` and `$ref` methods.

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {"$ref": "your path here"}, // the root schema, defining the object
        {
            "type": "array", // the schema.
            "items": {"$ref": "your path here"}
        }
    ]
}
```